# Every function $f:S\to T$ extends to a unique homomorphism $F(f):F(S)\to F(T)$ of free modules $F(S),F(T)$ over $R$ generated by $T$ and $S$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

> Show that every function $f:S\to T$ extends to a unique homomorphism
>
> $$F(f):F(S)\to F(T)$$
>
> of the free modules $F(S)$ and $F(T)$ over $R$ generated by $S$ and
>   $T$. Prove the following statements:
>
> a) $F(f\circ g) = F(f)\circ F(g)$
>
> b) $F(f)$ is an epimorphism $\iff$ $f$ is surjective
>
> c) $F(f)$ is a monomorphism $\iff$ $f$ is injective

Well, free modules $F(S)$ and $F(T)$ over $R$ generated by $S$ are modules $F(S),F(T)$, together with functions $f_s,f_t$ from $S$ to $F(S)$ and $T$ to  $F(T)$, such that for every $g_s,g_t$, from $S$ to $X_s$ and $T$ to $X_t$, there  exists unique homomorphisms $h_s,h_t$ such that $g_s =h_s\circ f_s$, $g_t =h_t\circ f_t$

To be honest, I didn't even understand the question itself. I tried to draw diagrams:[image]
but it makes no sense to me.

Could somebody explain to me what's happening?

Comment: What about putting $X_s := F(T)$, and $g_s := f_t\circ f$? What does that give you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F(f)$ is usually called "extension by $R$-linearity". That is, we can regard $F(S)$ and $F(T)$ and "formal (finite) $R$-linear combinations of the elements of $S$ and $T$, respectively".

So if we have $\alpha = r_1s_1 +\cdots + r_ns_n \in F(S)$, we set:

$F(f)(\alpha) = r_1f(s_1) + \cdots + r_nf(s_n) \in F(T)$.

Normally, your $f_S$ and $f_T$ are taken to be injections (it would be less confusing for you to use a different letter such as $\iota$ for these, to avoid confusion with your $f:S \to T$).

It should be clear that this extension of $f$ is uniquely defined, as this is what $F(f)$ *must* be if we are to have an $R$-module homomorphism (it has to be $R$-linear).

Proving statement a) requires a third basis set, $U$. So suppose we have:

$g: U \to S$, such that for any $i$ (we'll ignore questions for now of what the indexing set $I$ that $i$ belongs to, for now, is), we have $t_i = f(g(u_i)) = f(s_i)$.

We have: $F(f)\circ F(g)(r_1u_1 +\cdots + r_nu_n) = F(f)(F(g)(r_1u_1 +\cdots + r_nu_n))$

$= F(f)(r_1g(u_1)) +\cdots + r_ng(u_n)) = r_1f(g(u_1)) + c\dots + r_nf(g(u_n))$

$= r_1(f\circ g)(u_1) + \cdots + r_n(f \circ g)(u_n) = F(f\circ g)(r_1u_1 + \cdots + r_nu_n).$

Can you continue?